# Type safety in Generics

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

I have the below hierarchy of classes which just implement the imaginery functionality of encoding and decoding the animals from the given bytearrays.

```
public abstract class Animal {
}

class Tiger extends Animal{
    private String name;

    public void setName() { 
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

abstract class AnimalTransformer {
    public static <T> T decodeAnimalFromBytes(byte[] animalInBytes) {
        return null;
    }

    public static byte[] encodeAnimalInBytes(Animal animal) {
        return null;
    }
```

}

```
class TigerTransformer extends AnimalTransformer{
    public static Tiger decodeAnimalFromBytes(byte[] animalInBytes) {
        return new Tiger();
    }

    public static byte[] encodeAnimalinBytes(Tiger tiger) {
        return new byte[0];
    }
}
```

On overriding method from the AnimalTransformer abstract class in the TigerTransformer class which extends AnimalTransformer , i get the following warning

```
Type safety: The return type Tiger for decodeAnimalFromBytes(byte[]) from the type 
TigerTransformer needs unchecked conversion to conform to T 
from the type AnimalTransformer
```

I understand the cause of this warning but unfortunately i am not able to solve it as i am new to generics. Can someone briefly explain how can this warning be remedied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't try to 'override' with static methods.  It does not work the way you think  it does - the 'overridden' static methods can still be accessed from the subclass in devious (accidental) ways.  If you want overriding behavior, use local methods.

The warning is being generated because the `Tiger` method signature is not compatible with what the super-class method promises - that any class `<T>` chosen by the client can be decoded to, which is a very big, unfulfillable promise.

A better method would be:

```
abstract class AnimalTransformer<T extends Animal> {
  public T decodeAnimalFromBytes(byte[] animalInBytes) {
    return null;
  }
  public static byte[] encodeAnimalInBytes(T animal) {
    return null;
  }
}

class TigerTransformer extends AnimalTransformer<Tiger> {
  public Tiger decodeAnimalFromBytes(byte[] animalInBytes) {
    return new Tiger();
  }
  public byte[] encodeAnimalinBytes(Tiger tiger) {
      return new byte[0];
  }
}
```

This represents what you are trying to model more clearly - an `AnimalTransformer` provides transformation methods for some subclass of `Animal`, and it is up to the subclass, or anonymous implementation, to clarify which.

Comment: But i need to access the functionality only in a static way ie by not instantiating TigerTransformer, i want to access it like TigerTransformer.encodeToBytes() since instantiating this kind of classes doesn't make logical sense. Can't it accessed in a static way?

Comment: How does it not make logical sense?  If you need to, you can provide the TigerTransformer as a Singleton, if you're worried about multiple instances.  (Or, better yet, an AnimalTransformers class that provides all of the transformers).  If you really don't want to instantiate it, then using inheritance and genetics is what doesn't make sense - you can pick one or the other.

Comment: thanks..I meant it in a way that this class just provides the functionality of encoding and decoding so calling them with their class names ie by declaring static, i considered it to be better than instantiating.. And ya using singleton design pattern for these classes is fine for me so i would go with it..

Answer (score 2):

Note that there's no use in making the methods of AnimalTransformer static. Static methods don't override each other by inheritance. Furthermore, you are not binding the data type the transformer works on to the type of the decoded object (e.g., TigerTransformer can return Horse objects).

I would do the following instead, which I consider to be more type safe:

```
abstract class AnimalTransformer <T> {
    public abstract T decodeAnimalFromBytes(byte[] animalInBytes);

    public abstract byte[] encodeAnimalInBytes(T animal);
}
```